# Maven Release plugin: Doing the git push via https

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

On our jenkins box we clone our repo using https rather than ssh. However when I run the

```
mvn release:prepare
```

command it is pushing the commits via ssh. I am pretty sure it is because in my pom.xml in the scm section I have

```
<connection>scm:git:ssh:<internal package></connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh:<internal package></developerConnection>
```

I am pretty sure I can just change that to to be something like https: however where do I put the username and password so that it can connect?

Answer (score 1):

The credentials are stored in mavens settings file, so that the are not exposed in the pom.

Add a server section to your ~/.m2/settings file with your GitHub user/password, i.e.

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>GitHub</id>
        <username>[User]</username>
        <password>[Password]</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Add a property `<project.scm.id>GitHub</project.scm.id>` to your properties section in the pom. 
The reference to the server Id is not detailed in the release plugin config but the top level pom properties.